# Default values for Objects in OracleDB

Tags: sql, oracle, object, relational-database

Assuming I have an Object and Table declared like this:

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS OBJECT (
   some_property NUMBER(20)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TABLE MyTable OF MyType;
```

**How can I specify default values?** For normal tables, I would use something like `some_property NUMBER(20) DEFAULT 123`. Is it possible to use something similar for objects?

I know its possible to overload the constructor, but I'd like to be able to 
use the table the same way as without objects (That is, being able to specify only a small amount of columns when inserting data, and default the others).

Comment: You can create default constructor. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939882/setting-default-value-in-oracle-object-type-constructor-function.

Comment: Is it possible to use the existing syntax for inserting objects, e.g. `insert into MyTable(some_property) values (1)` and also `insert into MyTable values ()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of comment I add full answer due to misunderstanding

**DDL**

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS OBJECT (
   some_property NUMBER(20),
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION MyType(some_property number default 123) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY MyType AS
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION MyType(some_property number default 123)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  AS
  BEGIN
    SELF.some_property := some_property;
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE MyTable OF MyType;
```

**DML** works like this

```
-- Insert row with 123
INSERT INTO MyTable(some_property)
VALUES(MyType().some_property);
/

-- Insert row with 456
INSERT INTO MyTable(some_property)
VALUES(MyType(456).some_property);
/
```

In my opinion constructor is more flexible when create table with column object

```
create table testt (
      v mytype);
/

insert into testt values(MyType());
/

insert into testt values(MyType(456));
/
```

**Update**

I think you cann't write smt like this `insert into <table> values()` with object types using constructors. Also look at workaround with trigger [Oracle: specifying default value for object type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925999/oracle-specifying-default-value-for-object-type-column). But it isn't reliable.

**One more note**

Recent I know one more thing that you can add default value to nested table column as it was ordinary table. I thought that it is forbidden.

Look at this

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS OBJECT (
   some_property NUMBER(20),
   test_property NUMBER(20)
);

CREATE TABLE MyTable OF MyType
 ( some_property default '123' ); -- this simply transforms into 'alter table MYTABLE modify some_property default '123';'

 insert into MyTable(test_property) values(1)
```

Comment: Okay, seems there is no better way, my goal was to be able to use the same syntax for objects, so the existing code will still work.

Comment: @tobspr I add one note which I recently know from one quiz. This may be helpful for you.